# How to port forward SSH in virt-manager?

Tags: qemu, port-forwarding, virt-manager

I've set up a Gentoo guest in virt-manager but I'm unable to SSH to it from host machine. I've read that using qemu I need to do some port forwarding to be able to access ports in guest machine.
I couldn't find any option for this in virt-manager. How is it possible to do this?

I'm using Virt Manager 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 6):

Just to have this documented somewhere on the net:

I managed to do this some two years later by manually adding the relevant QEMU arguments to the KVM XML file (which holds the config for all the fancy virtualisation foo behind the scenes).

Here are the steps I performed to grant port forwarding to a user network;
in my case, forwarding the host's port 22222 to the guest's port 22:

My emulated machine will be called ubuntu18.04 here.

1. Open xml config for editing via virsh

   ```
   $ virsh -c qemu:///session edit ubuntu18.04
   ```
2. Find and remove the configuration for the "user"-type interface which may look somehow like this:

   ```
   <interface type='user'>
     <mac address='52:54:00:52:35:ff'/>
     <model type='rtl8139'/>
     <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
   </interface>
   ```
3. Add the QEMU namespace to the (root) domain tag:

   ```
   <domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
   ```
4. Manually add the now missing interface configuration as QEMU arguments somewhere inside the domain tag (e.g., as last child of `<domain>`):

   ```
   <qemu:commandline>
     <qemu:arg value='-netdev'/>
     <qemu:arg value='user,id=mynet.0,net=10.0.10.0/24,hostfwd=tcp::22222-:22'/>
     <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
     <qemu:arg value='rtl8139,netdev=mynet.0'/>
   </qemu:commandline>
   ```
5. Save the config and fire up/reboot the VM.
6. ssh away:

   ```
   ssh myusername@localhost -p 22222
   ```

Comment: As of Boxes 42.3, there's now a "Edit Configuration" button that can be used instead of virsh.  Just make sure the VM is off before using it, otherwise the settings get overwritten when it shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was the opposite. If the network device of a libvirt VM is configured to connect to `virbr0`, you should be able to access it from the host machine.

libvirt calls this "bridged" networking.  The other option for the network device, where this doesn't work, is called "user" networking.  If that is not your problem, you will have to provide more information.

More details here: http://xkahn.zoned.net/blog/2013/11/26/networking-and-gnome-boxes

Arch Linux wiki [suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libvirt#Networks) the virtual switch^Wbridge `vibr0` is part of the default configuration of the libvirt daemon, so you just need to make sure the VM is configured to use it.  They also link to a [detailed guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook). For `virbr0`, see the section "[NAT-based network](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/nat-based-network.html)"

Answer (score 0):

libvirt user networking has the ability to use the [passt](https://passt.top/passt/about/) transport backend instead of the default SLIRP.

When using this backend, port forwarding can be configured directly in the VM domain XML file with the  element.

To edit the XMLof a VM, use `virsh edit name_of_your_vm` which will open the file in your editor.

For example, to forward host tcp port 4022 to guest port 22, the following syntax can be used

```xml
...
<devices>
    ...
    <interface type='user'>
        <backend type='passt'/>
        <mac address='00:11:22:33:44:55'/>
        <portForward proto='tcp'>
            <range start='4022' to='22'/>
        </portForward>
    </interface>
    ...
</device>
...
```

It also supports forward multiple continuous port

```xml
<portForward proto='tcp'>
    <range start='31200' end='31300' to='6000' />
</portForward>
```

Forward udp port

```xml
<portForward proto='udp'>
    <range start='15055' to='5055' />
</portForward>
```

---

For detailed usage and examples, see [upstream documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#userspace-slirp-or-passt-connection)