# SSH into Gnome Boxes OS

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, gnome-boxes

I have received a virtual machine for my CS assignment. I have opened it in Gnome Boxes (just by double-clicking on the VM image), but I do not want to write code there, but on my local machine and then compile trough ssh on the virtual machine. The virtual machine has an .ova extension and in Boxes Preferences it says Broker QEMU Session, Display Protocol SPICE.
What should I use as remote IP for ssh? Are there any additional configurations of the VM to be made and how should I add them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is available with GNOME Boxes**

When you double-click on an Open Virtualization Format file, GNOME Boxes imports it automatically.

GNOME Boxes does not expose guests to SSH into. You are expected to have [SPICE guest additions](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html) installed on the guest to be able:

- to copy and paste text with a shared clipboard between the host and the guest and
- to drag and drop files into the guest.

This approach is supposed to be intuitively comprehensible for unsophisticated users, who GNOME [targets with this application](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes):

> While [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/) does a very good job as a virtual machine
> management software, it's very much tailored for system administration
> and virtual machines. Boxes, on the other hand, is targeted towards a
> typical desktop end-user who wants either a very safe and easy way to
> try out new operating systems or new (potentially unstable) versions
> of her/his favorite operating system(s), or needs to connect to a
> remote machine (home-office connection being a typical use-case). For
> this reason, Boxes does not provide many of the advanced options to
> tweak virtual machines provided by virt-manager. Instead, Boxes
> focuses on getting things working out of the box with very little
> input from user.
>
> That said, Boxes shares a lot of code with virt-manager project,
> mainly in the form of [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/), [libosinfo](https://libosinfo.org/) and [qemu](http://www.qemu-project.org/).

For the reference, there is [an inactive three-year-old proposal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-boxes/-/issues/149) to implement port forwarding in Boxes.

---

**Using different tools**

If you need to SSH into your guests, you might want to use the right tool for the task to configure your setup and resort to `virt-manager`. Typically, it can be done by configuring either a "[virtual network](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#virtual-network)" (for hosts with dynamic or wireless interfaces) or a "[bridge to LAN](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#bridge-to-lan)" (for hosts with static wired interfaces). On the other hand, Boxes configures guests with `user` mode networking, which employs a [userspace SLiRP stack](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#userspace-slirp-stack). You could use `virt-manager` to modify your existing setup and continue using your guests in Boxes afterwards if you like. I have not done this myself yet, so, if you choose to use `virt-manager`, you need a different tutorial.

---

**Port forwarding**

Another approach is to instruct QEMU to forward a port on the host to the port on the guest. You cannot modify the configuration file of the guest with a text editor because the changes will be disregarded and overwritten. You can modify it with `visrh`, which is available in `libvirt-clients` package (at least in Debian). You can learn the name of the domain in the second line of the "Troublshooting Log" available at the "System" tab in the guest "Properties" in Boxes. Alternatively, you can inspect the XML files in `~/.config/libvirt/qemu`. For example, in my installation the name of the domain associated with the installed guest machine is "boxes-unknown". To edit the configuration of that machine, I enter:

```
virsh edit boxes-unknown
```

The existing configuration of the network for the guest in my installation:

```xml
    <interface type='user'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:3d:69:49'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Unfortunately, you cannot just modify XML to only add port forwarding from the host to the guest. This feature is not implemented in the [domain XML format](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html) used by `libvirt`. [An email from 2013](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2013-April/msg00129.html) shows that there was an unsuccessful proposal for that feature. So, instead, we need to provide the relevant arguments to pass to QEMU on launching the guest. We cannot modify an existing network interface, so we just remove the XML part describing it to prevent it from being created. Instead, we have to replicate it in the arguments, which we want to pass to QEMU.

According to the the "Troubleshooting Log", in my setup the above network configuration corresponds to the following arguments:

```
-netdev user,id=hostnet0 \
-device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:3d:69:49,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 \
```

You can check the meaning of the arguments in `man qemu-system-x86_64`.

We don't want to copy the bus and the address because the automatic configuration will not take into account our custom QEMU arguments. This results in occasional collisions in address allocation, which prevents the guest from starting. Instead, we just allow it to be allocated to our custom network interface automatically.

Remember the device name. For example, if I don't specify `rtl8139`, it seems to configure `e1000` instead by default.

You need to modify the `<domain type='kvm'>` tag to include the XML namespace for the QEMU command line elements:

```xml
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
```

After that, you can add QEMU commandline arguments at the end right before the closing `</domain>` tag. In my example below, I add port forwarding to be able to `ssh localhost -p 2222` from the host and to be able to access a webserver at `http://localhost:8080` from a browser at the host. You probably need to modify this example according to your setup and your preferences. If necessary, the syntax of `hostfwd` argument can be read in `man qemu-system-x86_64`.

```xml
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-netdev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='user,id=hostnet0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8080-:80'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

The corresponding QEMU arguments are:

```
-device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0 \
-netdev user,id=hostnet0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8080-:80
```

It was not difficult to make the above XML from that, but [you can also use](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sub-sect-domain_commands-converting_qemu_arguments_to_domain_xml) `virsh domxml-from-native qemu-argv` to have it made for you.

This seems to be all we need for forwarding ports [according to QEMU wiki](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_get_SSH_access_to_a_guest).

Similar approach can be used with guests in `virt-manager` too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519067/423679

Don't skip XML validation when saving the file if `virsh` complains about errors. Try to fix you syntax first. Don't forget to keep backups of configuration files for just in case.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to do that is to use reverse SSH tunneling.

From inside the VM, run:

```bash
ssh -NT -R 2222:localhost:22 user@_gateway
```

where `user` is a username in the host.

Now, you can connect from the host using

```bash
ssh -p 2222 guestuser@localhost
```

where `guestuser` is a username is the guest.

If you don't want to run a command from the guest every boot, you can use `autossh` from a service.